# Recommended way of serving static content like videos/images on k8s

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, cdn, static-files

I'm pretty green with Kubernetes but have some experience with Google Container Engine. I'm struggling to find a good solution for serving media content from applications.

I've currently got media stored in a public bucket on Google Cloud Platform, and i'm running an NGINX proxy on local to take any path `/images` to the bucket for example:

```
    location /videos {
      proxy_pass https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket-name/videos;
      proxy_intercept_errors on;
      error_page 500 502 503 504 404 = @localmedia;
    }
```

What way would you recommend to serve media content on applications running on k8s?

Comment: Don't serve public static content from K8s, use Cloud Storage instead. If you are serving private content that requires authorization, I would use signed URLs with Cloud Storage.

Comment: I think my question phrasing was wrong. I don't want to serve content from k8s, i want to use cloud storage but would like to route requests from example.com/images to that instead of the service listening on example.com

Comment: so your question is how to run NGINX on k8s with `proxy_pass` ?

Comment: @Crou In part, also if that is the best way of proxying requests in k8s and how does that fit into the architecture

Comment: I think you are confused on how to implement URLs for your web services. You just specify the URL for the image in Cloud Storage in the client HTML. You don't listen for requests from your folder in K8s. You could but then that would require an HTTP redirection.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to serve static files form Google Cloud Storage the best way is to use directly the custom domain bucket feature no use K8S.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website

Basically you need to create your bucket as public with the name of the domain or subdomain you want to use and pint it as a CNAME to the special domain `c.storage.googleapis.com`

With that said, what is the main reason to use k8s?

Comment: Thanks wolmi, i'm using k8s for the availability and scaling on demand. It's not a static site i would just like to route all requests example.com/images to the cloud storage

Comment: In that case you can config the bucket with your custom domain as explained in the documentation and make your app use absolute URLs on that domain instead of relative ones, basically, you can use a domain to your app and another one or subdomain for the static content.